# Visaton speaker, how to wire up

Tags: soldering, wiring

I just got some [Visaton speakers](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/700000-724999/710739-da-01-de-2_8_CM_MINIATURLAUTSPRECHER_K_28_WP_8_OHM.pdf) in the mail.

But I'm not sure how to solder on the + and - wire.

There are four solder blobs (as seen in the picture below).
To which ones do I solder?

[image: visaton]

Comment: Why is this being voted off-topic?  These are miniature speakers commonly used in embedded designs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left side pads are connected together with a track and are the - (GREY circle) and the right side pads are also connected and go to the + of the speaker (RED circle).

[image]

If you want you can use an Ohm meter to check. Between + and - you will get a resistance of slightly lower than 8 Ohm and between the joined pad pairs you will get almost 0 Ohms.

Comment: You will probably hear a click when you measure the ~8 ohms on a low range.